# Can Hybrid apps access other apps on the device?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, ibm-mobilefirst

Is it anyway possible for Hybrid apps to read other apps data like SMS and mails. Like how google shows all imp mail and SMS data on their mobile (android) home page. Like Hotel Reservation details,  Ticket details etc....

guidelines or tutorial links are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application data is stored in a sandbox that is accessible only by the specific application.

It is therefore not allowed/possible for applications to access sandboxes of other applications.

Comment: Guess it should be possible only using Native apps?